# Has a "phase" change ever been considered between RF radiation and photons

Tags: electromagnetism

Where photons have properties such as spin and line of sight propagation, radio frequencies do not to the same degree, Photoelectric effects are attributed specifically to photons but not to radio waves.
Where a change of phase exists between for example liquids and gaseous states for the same elements, should we not consider the possibility that a change of phase may apply to energy?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is shows a total lack of effort or research.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The difference in behavior between radio waves and light is entirely due to the difference in frequency (and hence, wavelength).    The photoelectric effect would work equally well with radio waves if the energy needed to liberate an electron were very small.  The difference in that case is with the *material* not the *radiation*.   Light and radio both have exactly the same characteristics of line-of-sight propagation (or alternatively, the ability to "creep" around corners).  The difference is the size scale of potential obstacles compared to the wavelength.  Again, the difference is not that the *radiation* is different, but rather that the *surroundings* are different.

These differences in observations change smoothly and continuously as the frequency (wavelength) changes.  The current theories describe these phenomena perfectly.  There is no need at all to consider that a phase transition occurs, or that any change at all is called for in  our description of radiation.